# How to find the byte size of a table in Lua

Tags: lua

I'm writing a log aggregator and I want to send the logs if it reaches a max byte size. Thus is there a way in Lua to get to know the size of the variable (active_batch size)?

```
local batch = {
    flush_timeout
    retry_count
    batch_max_size
    batch_count

    batch_to_execute = {},
    active_batch = { entries = {}, count = 0, retries = 0 }
}
```

Comment: A variable doesn't have a byte size. An object might, but Lua doesn't have a way to tell how many bytes a table might represent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only can have total memory used by LUA by [collectgarbage](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-collectgarbage).
In this case I think that storing string len and sum of it will work.

Comment: Some notes. 1 Lua allocates memory for string only once. So if you have N exact same strings Lua creates only one copy of it. 2 There exists the lua-getsize module which allows to estimate Lua object size